# Duplicate cart items

Tags: cart, quote, session, quoteitem

community!

Bumped into an issue - duplicate items in a cart.

In the **quote** table, I have multiple quotes for the same customer. **Items_count** is increased like an exponent, eg 2, 3, 6, 178, 192. In the **quote_item** table there are duplicate records for the product.

Actually, there are no steps to reproduce. It happens for random cases and customers. For one day I have from 2-10 customers that have this issue. Average requests on the site are 140-160K per 6 hour.

Made some investigations in a newRelic, and saw a huge load for Redis session, but don’t know if it is the reason or consequence.

Want to mention some observations from customers' complaints and from hotjar sessions:
It can affect both customers (guest/registered); when a customer is a guest and added some products to the cart and then make sign up, then the cart has duplicate items. ; When the customer added products to the cart, applied the coupon code to get a discount and after that tries to remove some products from the cart and get duplicate items.

So, it has random steps, and the only path to research, in my opinion, think it is related to the session.

Will be appreciated by anyone who bumped into the same issue earlier and share their own experiences, or share yourself thoughts.

Magento CE 2.4.3-p3

Answer (score 0):

(Too low rep to comment)

Hey, I'm experiencing this exact same issue. It started about 20 days ago. I've been able to make no progress in diagnosing the issue. I Too saw spikes in Redis load, specifically CPU usage.

Have you learned anything new since posting?

Comment: *BUMP*
"What did you see?!" https://xkcd.com/979/